# Unable to Update libapache2-mod-php7.4 After Upgrade to 22.04

Tags: apt, apache2, php, 22.04

Last month, I had a smooth version upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 on my LAMP server. This month, while running my monthly patch maintenance, I got this error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-php7.4 : Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.1) but 8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
libapache2-mod-php8.0 : Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.1) but 8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Is this telling me that I *have* to upgrade PHP to version 8.1? I'm currently on 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix by typed below commands.
P.S. I have tried this on WSL2.

```
root@galaxy-book-go:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
root@galaxy-book-go:~# cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
root@galaxy-book-go:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# rm php7.4.conf
root@galaxy-book-go:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# rm php7.4.load
root@galaxy-book-go:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ln -s ../mods-available/php8.1.conf
root@galaxy-book-go:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ln -s ../mods-available/php8.1.load
root@galaxy-book-go:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ls -l ph*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 22 01:40 php8.1.conf -> ../mods-available/php8.1.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 22 01:40 php8.1.load -> ../mods-available/php8.1.load
root@galaxy-book-go:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I hope this helps.